# Google Spreadsheet Arrayformula for multiple columns conditions

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, array-formulas

I'm new on google spreadsheets, and I'm having this little problem:

I need to Sum values from column K (a project), for an specified person in cell B3, where the project belongs to the category RF or RM in column C, I've tried this but returns the sum of K like not conditions where applied...

```
=arrayformula(if(AND('SheetX'!I$3:I=B3;OR('SheetX'!C$3:C="RF";'SheetX'!C$3:C="RM"));sum('SheetX'!K$3:K);0))
```

Also

```
=arrayformula(Sum(if(AND('SheetX'!I$3:I=B3;OR('SheetX'!C$3:C="RF";'SheetX'!C$3:C="RM"));'SheetX'!K$3:K;0)))
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this simple issue.

Answer (score 3):

Already fixed. According to [this link](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/vTzff6zDhsE) "The OR function does not work in array expression (nor does the AND function; but the NOT function does work). The workaround is to use ADD instead of OR and MULTIPLY instead of AND instead; for practical reasons use the + operator associated with ADD and the * operator associated with MULTIPLY."

What I did was this:

```
=Sum(filter('SheetX'!K$3:K;'SheetX'!I$3:I=B3;('SheetX'!C$3:C="RF")+('SheetX'!C$3:C="RM")))
```

Thanks to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4j3uSqet14) that clear it up.